# What does the return statement mean in nav drawer?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer which has an onItemClickListener.

I use a switch case statement for each menu item, and when an item is clicked it runs the code inside each case block.

But what i dont understand is the return statement at the end, i read some posts where they use return false; and others use return true; at the end.

What should i use?

```
mNavigationView5.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull final MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.ic_edit:
                    //code for editing.
                    break;
                case R.id.ic_info:
                    //code for info.
                    break;
                case R.id.ic_remove:
                    //code for removing.
                    break;
            }
            return false; // should i return true here or false?
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return true to display the item as the selected item. Look at this for more reference - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.html#onNavigationItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)

Comment: Yeah i figured, but why do some posts here return false? or even youtube tutorials they also return false which confused me a bit.

Comment: You return false when you dont want to handle the item selected event. In simple terms, return true when you handle the event else false.

Comment: As such, returning true from these event listeners will stop the propagation of the event to other event listeners and will also block the callback to the default event handler in the View. So be certain that you want to terminate the event when you return true.

Comment: But when i return true at the end i will still be able to click another item right and run that code? for example i click on the edit item, go back and click on the info item?

Comment: Yes you will be able to . But that would be another event. Returning true/false will decide fate for current event only.